# Add maven-release-plugin to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, maven-plugin, libphonenumber

I am developing an Android app to handle phone numbers, using this library: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/tree/master/java.

This is the first time I tried to add a library to Android Studio and it is becoming a nightmare.

I tried to add the folder to a new directory in Android, and also to add it via the Maven Projects tab with the pom.xml file.
I know I have to modify the build.gradle file to add the dependencies, but I am not sure how to.

Comment: Thank you Der Golem for your answer. I solved it using the jar files that they provided here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/libphonenumber/ in the Maven repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven should be supported in android studio by default, but you can add it into repositories in `build.gradle` to be sure like this

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

and into dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0.4'
}
```

You should see library in `External Libraries` section on left in project overview after pressing `Sync Now`